# PHPUnit: "Invalid value passed to setPost()" when passing Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract converted using toArray()

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, php-5.3, zend-controller

The following code fails throws a Zend_Controller_Exception *("Invalid value passed to setPost(); must be either array of values or key/value pair")*

```
/** Model_Audit_Luminaire */
$luminaireModel = new Model_Audit_Luminaire();
if (!$fixture = $luminaireModel->getScheduleItem($scheduleId)) {
    $this->fail('Could not retrieve fixture from database');
}
$fixtureArray = $fixture->toArray();

$this->getRequest()
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->setPost($fixtureArray);
```

I did a var_dump() to ensure $fixtureArray was the correct type, and formatted properly...no visible problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are any of the columns in your schedule item row nullable?

The `setPost()` method calls itself for each key/value pair you pass in an array.  But if any value is null, it throws an exception.

You may have to loop over the array and `setPost()` only values that are non-null:

```
$this->getRequest()->setMethod("POST");
foreach ($fixtureArray as $key => $value) {
  if ($value === null) { continue; }
  $this->getRequest()->setPost($key, $value);
}
```

Or else ensure that the row you fetch from the database in your `getScheduleItem()` method contains no nulls.

Comment: Perfect. It was the null values that caused the error.  Thank you very much!